# Why I don't see the data of the oneToOne?

Tags: java, jpa

I am new in JPA

I created two entities Questionnaire and Patient

I want that Questionnaire  will have data of Patient.
Before I created the Questionnaire with only patientId but now I want to add new structure to get all the patientData.

I added new field of patientData and added new join( I hope I did it ok ).

The problem when I call to query AllQuestionnaires I didn't get data of patientData.

Could you please advise me ?

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "AllQuestionnaires", query = "select q from Questionnaire q order by q.patientId") })
public class Questionnaire implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Questionnaire() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private long patientId;
    private Timestamp created;





    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "patientId" ,referencedColumnName = "id" ,  insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Patient patientData;


    public Patient getPatient() {
        return patientData;
    }

    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        this.patientData = patient;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<QuestionnaireAnswer> answers;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getPatientId() {
        return patientId;
    }

    public void setPatientId(long patientId) {
        this.patientId = patientId;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public void setCreated(long created) {
        this.created = new Timestamp(created);
    }

    public List<QuestionnaireAnswer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(List<QuestionnaireAnswer> answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }

}
```

class Patient

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Transient;


@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "AllPatients", query = "select p from Patient p"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "PatientsByUserType", query = "select p from Patient p where p.userType = :userType"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "PatientByEmail", query = "select p from Patient p where p.email = :email"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "PatientById", query = "select p from Patient p where p.id = :id") })
    public class Patient implements Serializable {
        public enum UserType {
            PATIENT,
            CONTROL
        }
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Patient() {
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String email;
        private String password;
        private int gender;
        private Timestamp birthday;
        private Timestamp diagnoseDate;
        private Timestamp created;
        private UserType userType;

        @Transient
        private ArrayList<Task> lastSubmittedTasks;

        public UserType getUserType() {
            return userType;
        }

        public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
            this.userType = userType;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public int getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public void setGender(int gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public Timestamp getBirthday() {
            return birthday;
        }

        public void setBirthday(Timestamp birthday) {
            this.birthday = birthday;
        }

        public void setBirthday(long birthday) {
            this.birthday = new Timestamp(birthday);
        }

        public Timestamp getDiagnoseDate() {
            return diagnoseDate;
        }

        public void setDiagnoseDate(Timestamp diagnoseDate) {
            this.diagnoseDate = diagnoseDate;
        }

        public void setDiagnoseDate(long diagnoseDate) {
            this.diagnoseDate = new Timestamp(diagnoseDate);
        }

        public Timestamp getCreated() {
            return created;
        }

        public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
            this.created = created;
        }

        public void setCreated(long created) {
            this.created = new Timestamp(created);
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public ArrayList<Task> getLastSubmittedTask() {
            return lastSubmittedTasks;
        }

        public void setLastSubmittedTasks(ArrayList<Task> lastSubmittedTasks) {
            this.lastSubmittedTasks = lastSubmittedTasks;
        }

    }


@RequestMapping(value = "/questionnaires", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String createQuestionnaires(@RequestBody String body, HttpSession session) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        long patientId = (long) session.getAttribute("patientId");

        try {
            Questionnaire questionnaire = gson.fromJson(body, Questionnaire.class);
            questionnaire.setPatientId(patientId);
            questionnaire.setCreated(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(questionnaire);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

            return "{\"status\": \"OK\", \"id\": " + questionnaire.getId() + "}";
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You still have field `patientId` in your entity. Try removing it and all references to it and try again.

Comment: but I want the field patientId  and also the structure of all patient

Comment: this is how I add questionnaires createQuestionnaires

Comment: I thought that the field patientId in the joincolum meaning who is the source key

Comment: That could lead you into many problems later on. I can't say I'm 100% sure that's the problem, but why not remove the field and change `getPatientId()` to return `getPatientData().getId()`, with a null check?

Comment: I can do it but still I don't get thepatientData

Comment: Maric - could we have short chat ?

Comment: Sorry, no time right now. You can try to turn on SQL logging and see what actual SQL is being generated. It might give you a hint about the problem.

Comment: I tried also to change the join and it didn't work for  @OneToOne
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="patientId", referencedColumnName="id")
 private Patient patientData;

Comment: @Maric - could be that my join is wrong ?

Comment: `@JoinColumn(name = "patientId")` should be enough if you removed `patientId` mapping. Did you turn on SQL logging? Also, how are you checking that there are no patient data included in the results? Do you get any exceptions while executing the query?

Comment: how he know how to to the join the key in the patient is id and the key in Questionnaire is should be new key. do I need to add new field ?